# How to group 2-member subsets so that in a group no two subsets have a common elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, matching-theory

For a set $A$ with $n$ members, so that $A = \{1,2,3,...,n\}$. How can I group all subsets with two members, so that the intersection between any two subsets in the same group is an empty set and **no subsets are used more than once**?

For example if $n=4$, the six subsets with $2$ members, can be arranged like this:

Group-$1: (\{1,2\},\{3,4\})$

Group-$2: (\{1,3\},\{2,4\})$

Group-$3: (\{1,4\},\{2,3\})$

The other way of formating this problem, (That is if I have understood the concept correctly) Is to find a **Perfect matching** for a complete Graph and then removing the edges in the matching from the graph, and repeating the process until no edges are left.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

You need all the groups with doublets such that the intersection between any two subsets in the same group is an empty set. 
So, let's choose any $4$ elements from the set $A$ that would belong to a group. This can be done in $^nC_4$ ways.

But, as you can notice from the example that you have given, that for each of these 4 elements, you not just get $1$ group but $3$ groups.

So, **total number of groups** is given by: $\bf3$ $\bf^nC_4$ $\bf \ \text{[or }3\binom n4]$.

Example: For $n=5$,
We'll get $3\binom 54=15\text { groups.}$ These are as follows:
$G_1=(\{1,2\},\{3,4\})$
$G_2=(\{1,2\},\{3,5\})$
$G_3=(\{1,2\},\{4,5\})$
$G_4=(\{1,3\},\{2,4\})$
$G_5=(\{1,3\},\{2,5\})$
$G_6=(\{1,3\},\{4,5\})$
$G_7=(\{1,4\},\{2,3\})$
$G_8=(\{1,4\},\{2,5\})$
$G_9=(\{1,4\},\{3,5\})$
$G_{10}=(\{1,5\},\{2,3\})$
$G_{11}=(\{1,5\},\{2,4\})$
$G_{12}=(\{1,5\},\{3,4\})$
$G_{13}=(\{2,3\},\{4,5\})$
$G_{14}=(\{2,4\},\{3,5\})$
$G_{15}=(\{2,5\},\{3,4\})$

Comment: Thanks but I think I haven't asked my question in a clear way. Like the example I have in the question **subsets should only be a member of one group.**

Comment: @D-thec-tieve that's what I've done. Kindly check again. If you still think that it's not what you want, then could you be more clear please.